# Acquire shared Video Title

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am pushing a contact card to the glass to allow user to "share" with me.

But how would I acquire a title for the video the user has shared with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images or videos taken from Glass and shared with a `Contact` don't have a title by default. However, if your `Contact` has the `ADD_CAPTION` [`shareFeatures`](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts#sharingFeatures), this will let the user add a text caption before the media is shared with your Glassware.

The transcribed text will be in the `text` property of the timeline item.